# Own layout in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

Well, I'm testing "Dialog Fragment" and I've done a little program that when it starts show a Dialog Fragment with 3 options, the TextView on the main activity will show which option was selected. So basicly it's communication between Dialog and Activity. I was following an example with 2 buttons(positive and negative) but now I'm testing with my own layout with 3 button and I don't know how to continue...

Let's see the code:

3 Button in dialog_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then the DialogFragment class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TwoActionButtonsDialog extends DialogFragment {
     private DialogListener listener;

        public interface DialogListener {
            public void onDialogOption1(DialogFragment dialog);

            public void onDialogOption2(DialogFragment dialog);

            public void onDialogOption3(DialogFragment dialog);
        }

        // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the
        // NoticeDialogListener
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
            try {
                // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the
                // host
                listener = (DialogListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                        + " must implement DialogListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

            builder.setTitle("Test").setView(
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null));

           Button btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
           Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
           Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            return builder.create();
        }

}
```

And the main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        TwoActionButtonsDialog.DialogListener {



    private static final String TAG = "dialog";
    private TextView texto = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        showTwoActionButton();
    }

    public void showTwoActionButton() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new TwoActionButtonsDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
    }

    // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void onDialogOption1(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
       texto.setText("1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogOption2(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
         texto.setText("2");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogOption3(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        texto.setText("3");
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how to manage the buttons beacause I can't do:

```
Button btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
           Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
           Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

it throws an error: "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type TwoActionButtonsDialog". If I've inflated the layout why I can't acces to them?

What should I do?

Comment: please post you logcat.It helps in locating the error quickly

Comment: So basically you are trying to pop up a dialog with three selecting buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you inflate your view for a Dialog, save a result:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null)
builder.setTitle("Test").setView(v);
```

After that you can traverse your view for buttons:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```